# Browser is showing the LaTeX code instead of rendered math expressions

Tags: bug, mathjax

Yesterday I started to see only [math processing error] in mathoverflow.

Then I searched it up and cleaned the browser cache. After that, I can only see LaTeX code instead of rendered math expressions. My browser is Google Chrome running on Windows 7 Pro 64-bit.

Comment: Isn't http://meta.mathoverflow.net/ then the place to go? Maybe searching for ["math processing error"](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/search?q=math+processing+error) on meta helps...

Comment: @draks: Perhaps the OP meant math.SE instead of mathoverflow - certainly many newcomers seem to confuse them.

Comment: @Will: Could you post a screenshot of what you're seeing?